# How to quickly check various letter containment conditions on Java String?

Tags: java, string, ascii

What is a fast (execution time) and compact (amount of code) way of checking the following conditions on a `String` variable in Java:

1. variable contains any English letters (upper or lower case, so `a-zA-Z`)
2. variable contains only such letters
3. at least X% of the characters are such letters
4. starts with any such letter

Comment: Regular expression? Except for your 3rd option.

Comment: An IntStream with anyMatch for 1, allMatch for 2, filter and count() for 3, limit and anyMatch for 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Character.isLetter()` method tells if a char is a letter. It actually works for any language not just English. Iterate over all chars of the `String` let's call it `text` and count letters.

```
int letters = 0;
for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isLetter(c) {
        ++letters;
    }
}
```

or if you prefer Java 8 streams.

```
long letters = text.chars().filter(Character::isLetter).count();
```

Once you obtain the number of letters :

```
if (letters > 0) {
    // variable contains any English letters
}

if (letters == text.length()) {
    // variable contains only English letters
}

if ((double)letters/(double)text.length() >= (double)X/100.0) {
    // at least X% of chars are letters
}

if (text.length() > 0 && Character.isLetter(text.charAt(0))) {
    // starts with letter
}
```